# How to made a slice in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want do a slice a dataframe using a string "PP" that is in my column and get just the numbers that is afeter string:

Dataframe:

```
data = {'Serie':['28PP3097', '23228PP3097', '1822343218PP3097', '43642183097'],
    'FooBar':["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

I try:

```
df["Serie"] = np.where(df["Serie"].str.contains("PP"), df["Serie"][df["Serie"].str.find('PP')+1:],df["Serie"])
```

In this df, but it give me a erro ´cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by splitting and getting the last item after "PP":

```
data = {'Serie':['28PP3097', '23228PP3097', '1822343218PP3097', '43642183097'],
        'FooBar':["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Serie']=[i.split('PP')[-1] for i in df['Serie']]
```

Result

```
         Serie FooBar
0         3097    foo
1         3097    bar
2         3097    foo
3  43642183097    bar
```